# Upload my Game score on facebook

Tags: android, facebook, game-engine, game-physics

Hey I need a help in my game I am making a game for android smart phone.I am not making for Facebook. But I need a feature in my game that when player clear the level then he/she can update his/her score on Facebook as a status. what should I do please help me thank you in advance.

I follow this [**link**](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/) but something goes wrong.

Comment: what wrong is going on???

Comment: It gets a error for provider ID. and goes onFacebookError().My ID is correct

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Facebook developer site you'll find a step by step guide to implement their SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: I am not making game for Facebook.I want to just share player his score on his Timeline.

Comment: The best way to do this is via SSO using the FB SDK, the user still has to be logged in to simply share something and SSO is by far the best user experience for this.